# Bug on key up events in allegro

Tags: c, keyboard-events, allegro5

I'm doing a homework of my course using Allegro, as ordered.

I need to catch the key up events on keyboard, for this I used the follow code:

```
al_wait_for_event(evento, &ev);
if(ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP){
   if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_A || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_LEFT)
       cmd='a';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_W || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_UP)
            cmd='w';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_D || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_RIGHT)
            cmd='d';
   else if (ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_S || ev.keyboard.keycode==ALLEGRO_KEY_DOWN)
            cmd='s';
}
```

But this event return the value 6 times​​ at once!

On the code I have included (previously) this commands:

```
al_install_keyboard();
[...]
al_register_event_source(evento, al_get_keyboard_event_source());
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Before the ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP event, there will be the ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN.

Just change UP to DOWN and it'll do.

Comment: ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN and UP event don't refers to the pressing and releasing button events, but to the pressed state of UP and DOWN keys